# Scala - Accessible member up to directly inherited class

Tags: scala, access-modifiers, cake-pattern

Using cake pattern we can set a member only accessible to directly inherited trait

```
trait A { val a = 1 }
trait B { this: A => val b = a + 1 } // can access a 
trait C { this: B => val c = a + 1 } // will throw error because C cannot access a
```

I  want to apply this member access logic using `access modifier` rather than `self annotation`

For example,

```
trait A { protected[B] val a = 1 } 
trait B extends A { val b = a + 1 } 
trait C extends B { val c = a + 1 } // I want this to throw an error
```

Any solution?

Comment: If `C` is-a (extends) `B`, and `B` is-a `A`, then that means that `C` is-a `A`, and to be an `A` means you have-a `a`. If you were permitted to hide the `a` then `C` would no longer be-a `A`.

Comment: Also seems like bad design. Would make parent aware of a child.